# htaccess disallow root directory but allow other urls

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm using Xfilesharing for our company and I need to block the access to the main upload page by our internal IP range 192.168.230.1-225 and allow the download to every IP.
Using the following rule will block the main page but also the rest. But using a rule to allow the download breaks the rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^$                   /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]
RewriteCond    %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.230\.25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?$
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Z]{12})/([^/]+)/?$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?act=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^.*$ /error [R=302,L]
RewriteRule    ^del\-([0-9A-Z]{12})\-([0-9A-Z]+)/.+$    /cgi-bin/index.cgi?del=$1-$2 [L]
RewriteRule    ^admin$                  /?act=admin [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+).html$           /cgi-bin/index.cgi?act=page&tmpl=$1 [L]
```

The literal URL is http://www.example.com/MG4YBAOW18QH/3.png and the rule: `^([0-9A-Z]{12})/([^\/]+)$       /cgi-bin/index.cgi?act=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L]`

Comment: What is URL of your upload page?

Comment: this rule matches the download link:RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Z]{12})/([^\/]+)$        /cgi-bin/index.cgi?act=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L] and literal is site.com/MG4YBAOW18QH/3.png

Answer (score 0):

Have your download rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.230\.\d+
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z]{12})/([^/]+)/?$ - [F,NC]

RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z]{12})/([^/]+)/?$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?act=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: using your rewrite i still can access both pages and gives a redirect loop over the images and css.I updated my main rewrite with yours

Comment: You can still access `http://www.example.com/MG4YBAOW18QH/3.png` from `192.168.230.25` IP? Check what IP are you getting from Apache logs?

Comment: My ip is 192.168.230.1

Comment: But your rewrite condition is not even blocking this IP. Can you clarify your requirements.

Comment: i clarified with the range IP